# WMI Remote connection, failing

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

### Solved, have got the answer in other thread if any1 needs it for reference..

### Explanation:

Local WMI worked, but now I'm trying to do it remotely. I've tried disabling both firewalls, checking WMI permissions (Logging in with administrator account) and that should be fine. Yet when trying to connect with IP I keep getting: 0x800706BA error, yet when using the PC-name, no error shows, but WMI isn't showing any result.

Lansweeper succeeded. (http://www.lansweeper.com/kb/3/WMI-Access-is-denied.html)

Connection Error: 0x800706BA at managementScope.Connect()

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC
>   server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) at
>   System.Management.ThreadDispatch.Start() at
>   System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize() at
>   System.Management.ManagementScope.Connect() at
>   Admin_Helper.frmRemoteInformation.button1_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Stef\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Admin_Helper\Admin_Helper\frmRemoteInformation.cs: line
>   110 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   message, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

-

### Question:

What would be the best way to check if the connection has succeeded/failed or its the wmi and how to fix it.

```
 ManagementScope managementScope;
    ObjectQuery query;
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionOptions remoteConnectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            remoteConnectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            remoteConnectionOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
            remoteConnectionOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
            remoteConnectionOptions.Username = txtUsername.Text;
            remoteConnectionOptions.Password = txtPassword.Text;

            managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + txtServer.Text + @"\root\CIMV2", remoteConnectionOptions);
            managementScope.Connect();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }

    private void cmbClassSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var dctPropertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            query = new ObjectQuery(cmbClassSelection.SelectedItem.ToString());
            new Thread(() => FindWMI(managementScope, query, dctPropertyList, lstProperties)).Start();
    }
    private void FindWMI(ManagementScope scope, ObjectQuery query, Dictionary<string, string> dct, ListView listView)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ListViewItem> itemsList = new List<ListViewItem>();

            ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                listView.Items.Clear();
            }));

            foreach (ManagementObject moObject in moSearcher.Get())
            {
                if (moObject != null)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData propData in moObject.Properties)
                    {
                        if (propData.Value != null && propData.Value.ToString() != "" && propData.Name != null && propData.Name != "")
                            dct[propData.Name] = propData.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> listItem in dct)
            {
                ListViewItem lstItem = new ListViewItem(listItem.Key);
                lstItem.SubItems.Add(listItem.Value);
                itemsList.Add(lstItem);
            }

            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                listView.Items.AddRange(itemsList.ToArray());
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

### UPDATE:

Problem seems to be something with WMI.

### UPDATE2:

. Most stupid mistake ever. Had to change 2 things:

1. `remoteConnectionOptions.Username = txtUsername.Text; ==> remoteConnectionOptions.Username = txtServer.Text + @"\" + txtUsername.Text;`
   Which would give: "Server-Name\Username"
2. Query = new ObjectQuery(cmbClassSelection.SelectedItem.ToString()); ==>
   objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("select * from " + cmbClassSelection.SelectedItem.ToString());

Forgot the "select * from " since I work with the combobox.

In case anyone is going to need the code, I'll update it after I clean it up a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself:

Be sure to check firewall & WMI settings...

Ok so one way to check if the connection has succeeded is:

```
ManagementScope myscope = new ManagementScope(@"\\Server\Username", ConnectionOptions);

if (myscope.IsConnected) { MessageBox.Show("Connected"); } else { MessageBox.Show("Disconnected"); }
```

Now you know if your connection works or not, then just search for a standard query to try it out and compare it to your own code...

Example: [example on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

### Finished Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Admin_Helper
{
public partial class frmRemoteInformation : Form
{
    public frmRemoteInformation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string strServername;
    string strUsername;
    string strPassword;
    string strClassSelection;
    ConnectionOptions rcOptions;
    ManagementObjectCollection moCollection;
    ObjectQuery oQuery;
    ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher;
    ManagementScope mScope;

    private void frmRemoteInformation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mScope.IsConnected == true) { lblConnectionStateWarning.Text = "Connected"; } else { lblConnectionStateWarning.Text = "Disconnected"; } //I have a label that displays connectionstate, you can leave that out
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            strServername = txtServer.Text;
            strUsername = txtUsername.Text;
            strPassword = txtPassword.Text;

            remoteConnection(strServername, strUsername, strPassword);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }

    private void cmbClassSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var dctPropertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            strClassSelection = cmbClassSelection.SelectedItem.ToString();
            new Thread(() => FindWMI(strServername, strClassSelection, rcOptions, dctPropertyList, lstProperties)).Start();
    }

    private void remoteConnection(string servername, string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            rcOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            rcOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
            rcOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            rcOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
            rcOptions.Username = servername + @"\" + username;
            rcOptions.Password = password;

            mScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", servername), rcOptions);
            mScope.Connect();
            if (mScope.IsConnected == true) { MessageBox.Show("Connection Succeeded", "Alert"); } else { MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed", "Alert"); }
            if (mScope.IsConnected == true) { lblConnectionStateWarning.Text = "Connected"; } else { lblConnectionStateWarning.Text = "Disconnected"; } //I have a label that displays connectionstate, you can leave that out

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }

    private void FindWMI(string servername, string classSelection, ConnectionOptions rcOptions, Dictionary<string, string> dct, ListView listView)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ListViewItem> itemsList = new List<ListViewItem>();
            oQuery = new ObjectQuery("select * from " + classSelection);
            moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mScope, oQuery);
            moCollection = moSearcher.Get();

            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                listView.Items.Clear();
            }));

            foreach (ManagementObject mObject in moCollection)
            {
                if (mObject != null)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyData propData in mObject.Properties)
                    {
                        if (propData.Value != null && propData.Value.ToString() != "" && propData.Name != null && propData.Name != "")
                            dct[propData.Name] = propData.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> listItem in dct)
            {
                ListViewItem lstItem = new ListViewItem(listItem.Key);
                lstItem.SubItems.Add(listItem.Value);
                itemsList.Add(lstItem);
            }

            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                listView.Items.AddRange(itemsList.ToArray());
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    private void frmRemoteInformation_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process myProc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (myProc.ProcessName == "WmiPrvSE")
            {
                myProc.Kill();
            }
        }

        if (mScope.IsConnected == true) { mScope.Options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.None; }; //Change option so that the connection closes, no disconnect option
    }

}
}
```